# Can anyone give an example of decomposing a function defined on R into an absolutely continuous part and singularly continuous part?

Tags: measure-theory

Can anyone give an example of decomposing a function defined on the real line into an absolutely continuous part and a singularly continuous part?

Comment: It's kinda hard, because usually we would cook up such a mixed function by writing down an absolutely continuous function and a singularly continuous function and adding them, in which case the decomposition is trivial. Functions with a nonzero part of both don't tend to appear "in the wild" very much.

Comment: An example where a mixed function is cooked up by writing down an absolutely continuous function and a singularly continuous function and adding them should be sufficient for this question.

Comment: If the function is of bounded variation, its absolutely continuous part is the integral of its derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most familiar example of a singular function is the so-called Cantor function, call it $c(x)$. This is the CDF of the uniform distribution on the Cantor set. It can be defined by the following algorithm:

- Write the ternary expansion of $x$.
- Find the first 1; make all digits after it be zero.
- Make all remaining 2s into 1s.
- Interpret the result as a binary expansion.

This is a nondecreasing continuous function which is $0$ at $0$ and $1$ at $1$. Its derivative exists almost everywhere (namely, off the Cantor set) but is zero where it exists.

A mixed function can be given by $f(x)=x+c(x)$. This gets used in one proof that there exists a Lebesgue measurable set which is not Borel measurable.